# Why do exist the two equal interfaces in the .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

Why do exist the two equal interfaces in the .NET Framework?

The `System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window`, and the `System.Windows.Interop.IWin32Window`.

Thank's.

Comment: I'd suppose one is for use with Windows Forms, while the other one (the `Interop` one) is supposed to be used in WPF applications (note that it is located in *PresentationCore.dll*, one of the WPF core assemblies). You usually don't want to reference WinForms assemblies when creating anything WPF-only. (This is a comment, not an answer, because I've never used any of the `IWin32Window` interfaces and I'm not sure whether that's the appropriate distincition.)

Comment: I don't quite understand the *close* votes here. This question can very well be answered in a definitive way, namely with the reason for original design decision.

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window` when you are working with `WinForms`.
Use `System.Windows.Interop.IWin32Window` when you are working with `WPF`.

The main purpose of existing these two interfaces is, that you don't need to refer to `WinForms` specific assemblies, when you are working with `WPF` and vice versa.

Comment: But they (Microsoft) can locate common interfaces in some common library. For example: commonInterfaces.dll.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window` exists since `.NET Framework 1.0`. While `System.Windows.Interop.IWin32Window` appeared in `.NET Framework 3.0`. Probably the trouble is with backward compability.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's just for a convenience, so you don't need a completely unrelated `Forms` assembly, then you are actually using WPF, so you avoid short name clashes and IntelliSense trashing.